# Laravel 5.6 unable access user details after login with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, logging, laravel-5.6

I have login modal in view and want to login with Ajax in Laravel 5.6. Ajax returns me 'Success' message, but when I refresh window location with JS, User data is not accessible from blade template. Here is my code

> My Controller

```
  protected function authenticated(Request $request)
{
    $auth = false;

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        $auth = true; // Success
        $request->session()->put('current_user',Auth::user());

    }

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'auth' => $auth,
            'intended' => URL::previous()
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->intended(URL::route('contact'));
    }
    return redirect(URL::route('login_page'));
}
```

> My Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var loginForm = $("#loginForm");
        loginForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = loginForm.serialize();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ route('ajax_login') }}",
                type:'POST',
                data:formData,
                success:function(data){
                    // console.log(data);
                    window.location.href = '/'
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('failed');
                }
            });
        });
```

> My Route

```
    Route::post('/user-login', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticated')->name('ajax_login');
```

Comment: I guess when redirecting with JS it is not adding the proper response to the request.

Comment: Do you mean data from `current_user`?

Comment: Actually I want to use dropdown menu which held user account link, logout button and user image, after log in completed. Without Ajax I can get what I need, but when I try to login with ajax request it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you refresh using `window.location.reload` all the javascript files will be reloaded and the variables will be cleaned.
You can store your data in the local storage `window.localStorage.putItem('key', object)` or directly use your data using jQuery, it depends on yout need.

Hopes it helps.